Period of binary sequences
Let $k>0$ be an integer. Consider a finite binary sequence $\sigma=(b_0,b_1,...,b_{n-1})$ where $n=2\cdot 3 \cdots p_k $ is the product of the first $k$ primes, and $b_i=1$ iff $i$ is divisible by any prime in $2,...,p_k$. For instance, if $k=2$, we have $n=2\cdot 3=6$ and $\sigma=(1,0,1,1,1,0)$.
Consider now the infinite sequence $\sigma^\infty$ obtained by repeating $\sigma$ infinitely many times.
Question: is it true that the minimal period of $\sigma^\infty$ is $n$? And how to prove it? Any reference to this problem would be appreciated.

What have you tried? What is your guess? How would you approach it? $\quad$   FYI Instead of defining $ \sigma^\infty$ as repeating $\sigma$ infinitely many times, you can simplify it consider the infinite sequence where $b_i=1$ iff $i$ is divisible by any prime in $2,...,p_k$.

First note that $n$ is obviously $0$ modulo each of the primes up to $p_k$. So for any number $N$, we have that $N\equiv N-n\mod p_j$ for each $1\leq j\leq k$. This immediately means that $\sigma^\infty$ is periodic with period $n$. If $m$ is the minimal period of $\sigma^\infty$, we must have that $m|n$.
Now assume $n=m\cdot d$ for some $d\geq 2$. But then, by assumption, $b_1=b_{m+1}=\dots=b_{m(d-1)+1}=0$, meaning, in particular, that each of the numbers $1,m+1,\dots,m(d-1)+1$ is coprime with $d$. But, since $m$ is coprime with $d$, the map $\phi:\mathbb (Z_d,+)\to(\mathbb Z_d,+)$ given by $\phi(k)=\phi(1+mk)$ is injective since the condition $1+mk=1+m\ell$ implies $m(k-\ell)=0$ which is only possible if $k=\ell$. Since $\mathbb Z_d$ is finite, $\phi$ is then also surjective. So there exists $0\leq k\leq d-1$ such that $1+mk\equiv 0 \mod d$, contradiction.

Thanks. I assume you mean $\phi(k)=(1+mk) \bmod d$? Also, in concluding $k=\ell$ from $mk=m\ell \bmod d$ one should use the fact that $m$ is coprime with $d$, I guess.

Exactly. I am working on the group $\mathbb Z_d$ of residues modulo $d$, where addition is defined $\mod d$. And indeed, the only way the equation $m(k-\ell)\equiv 0 \mod d$ has a non-trivial solution $k\not \equiv \ell \mod d$ is if $m$ and $d$ are not coprime. If they are coprime, $m$ is invertible with respect to multiplication in $\mathbb Z_d$, so we just get that $k\equiv \ell \mod d$, meaning that $k=\ell$ as elements in $\mathbb Z_d$.

If you are not used to the group notation, you can also do this with direct modular arithmetic. If $\gcd(m,d)=1$, then there exists some $0\leq k\leq d-1$ such that $mk \equiv -1 \mod d$. This is equivalent to finding some integer $a$ such that $mk = ad-1$, or, rearranging, to the existence of some integer $a$ such that $1=ad-mk$, which is an immediate consequence of Bezout's lemma. If one needs clarification as to why the $k$ can be chosen explicitly between $0$ and $d-1$, one can look at Euclid's algorithm.
